# display single item (introtext) from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

The question is so basic that nobody talk about it...

This query work but I can't make it with php.

SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127

Comment: Why can't you make it work with PHP? Are you getting an error? Are you connecting correctly to the DB before running the query?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply!when I put that [code]<? php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query); ?>[/code] I get that [code]Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 7[/code]

Comment: I apologize, first time here, with a phone...

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! when I put that 

`<? php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query); ?>`

 I get that: 

 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 7'<? php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query); ?>`

Comment: [code]$db =& JFactory::getDBO();[/code] That's a joomla extension. Is your website using Joomla? If so, do you have that extension enabled?

Comment: yes  I m writting inside a joomla module that enable php (jumi module) , if it was your question (thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

> It is not an sql related error.

Use **[mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)** to execute the query:

```
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query);
```

**UPDATE:**

There is a very `minor bug` in your code. The error is occurring due to your **starting php tag**.

Use **`<?php`** instead of **`<? php`**. You have an extra **whitespace** between `<?` and `php`. Remove it and it will work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! when I put that 

`<? php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query); ?>`

 I get that

 `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 7'<? php
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query); ?>`

Comment: (this forum is tricky with a phone!) this code is written inside an new module from joomla, (there is nothing else).

Comment: It is getting better, it seems that I have a connection pb with the db

Comment: `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 4

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 4`

Comment: I am writing this code inside a joomla modul to access to the same web site joomla database, Am I suppose to write a login and password (I guess it is only require for external db, do you confirm?)

Comment: Maybe. Have you do it trying out that way?

Comment: I do not feel comfortable to add psw and login into this code, I guess there is an other way since the code is launch from inside the db. But thanks for your time and advice!

Comment: Can you see mysqld.sock file in this directory /var/run/mysqld/ ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that You use MySQLi class.
I have my own improved mysqli class written, but not finished. But still, if needed, ask.

Comment: Thank you for that but I need to work with the current db. Have a good day!